# Flash Dynamic text in embedded movie

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Hi I have my movie in the main timeline and then have a smaller clip in which there is a dynamic text box. In that smaller movie I have some actionscript

```
myVars = new LoadVars();
myVars.load("http://preview.domain.co.uk/inc/loadVars.php");

myVars.percentage

myVars.onLoad = function() {
    text_box.text = this.percentage;
};
```

but when I play the movie it doesn't work. However if I move the dynamic textbox onto the main timeline it works.

Please can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

If your text_box is not in the same clip of you action script it will not work. if your text_box is in the parent clip by example doing `_parent.text_box.text` will work.

Check the clip hierarchy to see where is your actionscript and where is your text_box.

Comment: my actionscript is in the same clip as my textbox but the clip itsself is a child of the main timeline and will not work however if I move my textbox and as to  the main timeline it works